# IFeatureCollection is disposed Object name: Collection in a Task?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to run a `Task` to save the logs into a database table.

But it seems like that the HttpContext is disposedin the other thread.

Here is my code:

```cs
_ = Task.Run(() =>
{
    using (var db = LogContext())
    {
        var request = new LoginLog
        {
            Url = context.HttpContext.Request.Path,
            UserAgent = context.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers?[HeaderNames.UserAgent].ToString()
        };
        await db.AddAsync(request);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
});
```

Here is the exception trackInfo:

```cs
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ThrowContextDisposed()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.Fetch[TFeature, TState](TFeature & cached, TState state, Func`2 factory)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Path()
at PowerMan.Applet.Api.Infrastructure.Filters.RequestFilter.<> c__DisplayClass4_0.< OnActionExecutionAsync > b__1() in / Users / zhaojing / Projects / PowerMan.Api / PowerMan / PowerMan.Applet / PowerMan.Applet.Api / Infrastructure / Filters / RequestFilter.cs:line 112
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<> c.<.cctor > b__274_0(Object obj)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

Is it the Task which make the exceptions?

Comment: HttpContext is [not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#httpcontext-access-from-a-background-thread). Have you considered to use `IHttpContextAccessor` to retrieve the related HttpContext?

Comment: @PeterCsala how to use IHttpContextAccessor?

Comment: On the same MSDN page, but a  [bit earlier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components) it describes how to register `HttpContextAccessor` into the services. Then you have to create a class, which can receive an accessor instance via DI. Then you can use it in that class's methods. So you should move your logging logic into that class (without the surrounding `Task.Run`).

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely the context is disposed after the request completes.
So you will need to capture the values you will need before starting the background operation:

```
var url = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
var userAgent = context.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers?[HeaderNames.UserAgent].ToString();
_ = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var db =LogContext())
                {
                    var request = new LoginLog
                    {
                        Url = url,
                        UserAgent = userAgent
                    };
                    await db.AddAsync(request);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            });
```

Comment: someone tolds me async to the database easily to cause deadlock.is it right?

Comment: I don't think it's any more likely to cause deadlocks than any other I/O operation. As long as you are not waiting for Tasks to complete synchronously, you shouldn't run into issues generally. I would actually suggest using `await db.SaveChangesAsync()` here as well.

Comment: you mean the operations should be async of the DbContext?